# Contract does not accept eth sent from another contract

Tags: transfer, fallback-function

Hi I try to send ETH from Sender contract to Receiver contract by calling sendPayment function. But I get an error. I know that the issue is the require statement in the fallback function because without it it works. Could anyone advise me how I can get Receiver contract to receive ETH with this condition (the balance must be 0 when receiving ETH). Thank you.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Receiver {
    
    function viewBalance () public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function () external payable {
        require(address(this).balance == 0);
    }
}

contract Sender {
    Receiver receiver;

    constructor (Receiver _receiver, string memory blank) public {
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

    function sendPayment () public payable {
        address(receiver).transfer(msg.value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for a way to send eth to that contract, while it has a non-zero balance and the following condition `require(address(this).balance == 0);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
require(address(this).balance == msg.value);
```

As the balance already contains the ether that was just received (msg.value), this will verify that there was no balance in the contract prior to this transaction.

---

Note that somebody can brink your contract by just sending 1 wei to it.